# HTMX - Call a function after specific (Enter) keyup with hx-on

Tags: javascript, htmx

I am trying to call a javascript function after a **SPECIFIC** keyup event.

```html
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="description" 
    placeholder="task" 
    id="field-description"
    hx-on:keyup="alert('foo')"                    <------- WORKS
    hx-on:keyup[key=='Enter']="alert('foo')"      <------- DOESN'T WORK
>
```

How can I detect the Enter keypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using.

```html
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="description" 
    placeholder="task" 
    id="field-description"
    hx-on:keyup="
        if (event.key=='Enter') {
            alert('foo');
        }
    "
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be utilising the hx-on:keyup attribute, indicating that you are utilising the Hyperscript syntax, potentially working together with the HyperHTML or htmx library. You can use the event.keyCode or event.key property together with an if statement to determine when the Enter key is pressed.

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    name="description" 
    placeholder="task" 
    id="field-description"
    hx-on:keyup="handleKeyup(event)"
>

<script>
    function handleKeyup(event) {
        // Check if the pressed key is Enter
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            alert('Enter key pressed!');
            // Call your specific JavaScript function here
            yourFunction();
        }
    }

    //JavaScript function
    function yourFunction() {
        console.log('Specific function called after Enter keypress');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware of this approach, I was hoping for a more HTMX-y solution.

Comment: @Ivan i dont think html have `<elem attr[inner-attr]="val">` syntax. maybe you could look into alpine's approach https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#keyboard-events . they use @keyup.enter

Answer (score 1):

I tried `keyup[enterKey]`, `keyup[key='Enter']`, `keyup[keyCode==13]`, nothing worked. Only way I could get it to work was:

```
hx-on:keyup="keyCode==13&&alert('foo')"
```